# Battery won't hold a charge. 2001 Ford Mustang

Tags: battery

2001 Ford Mustang V6. Bought brand new battery in Nov 2013. I tested the core of the alternator at the same time as buying the battery and it tested good. I also switched out a relay in the engine to see if that would help.

I can jump start the car but it still will not hold the charge after turning the car off. any ideas?

Comment: How long does it take for it to drain (or lose charge)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a defective battery. You may want to go have it checked. Also, sometimes batteries sit on the shelf awhile before they're sold. Was it properly charged before you put it in the car?

Comment: I just recently had a new battery go bad.  It didn't seem to hold charge real well, car would barely start after sitting for 2 weeks (never had a problem leaving it for even 2 months before).  Just a few days ago it failed completely, cooking off acid (smells horrible) and overheating.  The battery was only 9 months old...